# Item in Model does not update in View in real-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In my project, I have a view where a user can see ImageCollections which have subfolders and images (set up through MVVM and models). One of the features I wanted to implement is a little image holder where the next image unseen yet is displayed. I have set it up in the ImageCollection model below and it works a treat BUT: it does not update in real-time.

What i mean is that when I do click an image as being viewed, the ShowNextToWatchImage Image does not update automatically in the view (it does show the correct new one if I exit the app and relaunch it or when I reopen the folder).

How can I fix this?

**In the model:**

```
public Image ShowNextToWatchImage
        {
            get
            {
                var found = false;
                Image nextToWatchImage = null;
                foreach (var folder in Folders)
                {
                    foreach (var image in folder.Images)
                    {
                        if (!image.ImageHasBeenViewed)
                        {
                            nextToWatchImage = image;
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        nextToWatchImage = image;
                    }
                    if (found)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return nextToWatchImage;
            }
            set
            {
                _showNextToWatchImage = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowNextToWatchImage);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

After trying to implement Sheridan's answer, I have the following (which I am sure I balzed up in some way) which give me nothing (or at least shows nothing in the view for that item.

```
public class Collection : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private Image _showNextToWatchImage;

        public Collection()
        {
            Folders = new List<Folder>();
        }

        public Image ShowNextToWatchImage
        {
            get { return _showNextToWatchImage; }
            set
            {
                _showNextToWatchImage = value;
                UpdateNextToWatchImage();
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowNextToWatchImage);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateNextToWatchImage()
        {
            var found = false;
            Image nextToWatchImage = null;
            foreach (var folder in Folders)
            {
                foreach (var image in folder.Images)
                {
                    if (!image.ImageHasBeenViewed)
                    {
                        nextToWatchImage = image;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    nextToWatchImage = image;
                }
                if (found)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ShowNextToWatchImage = nextToWatchImage;
        }

        public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Maybe your problem is not in ViewModel, but in View. Do you use TwoWay BindMode?

Comment: In order to update ViewModel via View (in real time) you need to specify TwoWay Binding on View's side as @Piotr Czarnecki pointed out.

Comment: What is `folder.Images`? Show the definition, please.

Comment: Just a note: You named your property `ShowNextToWatchImage`, which begins with a verb. In general, methods should be used to take some action, and the properties should hold state. I would have a `NextToWatchImage` property, and a `SetNextToWatchImage()` method, and call the method whenever the property should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `NotifyOfPropertyChange` when the value changes, but you're actually changing the value in the getter instead of the setter... try creating a new method named `UpdateNextImage` and putting your code to determine the next `Image` in there instead:

```
public Image ShowNextToWatchImage
{
    get
    {
        return _showNextToWatchImage;
    }
    set
    {
        _showNextToWatchImage = value;
        UpdateNextImage();
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowNextToWatchImage);
    }
}
```

UPDATE >>>

I'm still not 100% sure of your set up (it's best if you can show us *all* of your related code), but you say that you want this to update when you click on an `Image`. This makes me think that you have a click or `Command` handler somewhere. If this is correct, then I would recommend that you put your next selection functionality in there instead:

```
private void Image_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowNextToWatchImage = GetNextImage();
}

private Image GetNextImage()
{
    var found = false;
    Image nextToWatchImage = null;
    foreach (var folder in Folders)
    {
        foreach (var image in folder.Images)
        {
            if (!image.ImageHasBeenViewed)
            {
                nextToWatchImage = image;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            nextToWatchImage = image;
        }
        if (found)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return nextToWatchImage;        
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the better option but where do I put that new method? in the collection model, the image model or in the ViewModel?

Comment: Just underneath the property? It has to be accessible from the property.

Comment: I updated my original post with your suggestion but it is failing at the mo. could you have a peek for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `mode=TwoWay` on the binding in your XAML? So: `{Binding ShowNextToWatchImage, Mode=TwoWay}`.

Comment: Yes I have but it does not wish to work. I am going to try a work around now and see how that goes

Comment: Can you switch these two lines: `_showNextToWatchImage = value; UpdateNextToWatchImage();`? You set `ShowNextToWatchImage` property and after that you execute the method where you **again** set the same property, sounds a little strange to me.